# Можно ли получить целый экземпляр из ItemsCotnrol.Items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-commands

У меня есть список, получающий элементы через привязку к свойству его `VM`ки:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Удалить" Command="{Binding ElementName=Parent, Path=DataContext.DeleteItem" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Здесь есть такая кнопка:

```
<Button Content="Удалить" Command="{Binding ElementName=Parent, Path=DataContext.DeleteItem" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
```

Чтобы команда сработала нормально, мне нужно передавать `Item.Id` и уже в коде команды мне нужно искать элемент с этим индексом через поиск совпадения по Id. Это неудобно.

Можно ли как-то передать в команду сам объект `Item`, а не его свойство `Id`?

Comment: `{Binding Id}` -> `{Binding}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто нужно не писать имя свойства:

```
{Binding Id} -> {Binding}
```